# split column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:
[image]

My target table:
[image]

So, basically what I'm trying to do is to split the date column to `date_1` and `date_2`.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask questions. You should provide some more information.

Comment: It can be done with some simple aggregation, using the fact that `max(null, date)` will return `date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Customer, 
       MAX(COVID1) AS COVID1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN COVID1 IS NOT NULL THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Date_1, 
       MAX(COVID2) AS COVID2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN COVID2 IS NOT NULL THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Date_2 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY Customer;
```